# List Partitioning in Postgres 12

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

```
CREATE TABLE countrymeasurements
(
  countrycode int NOT NULL,
  countryname character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  languagename character varying (30) NOT NULL,
  daysofoperation character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  salesparts    bigint,
  replaceparts  bigint
)
 PARTITION BY LIST(countrycode)
 (
  partition india values(1),
  partition japan values(2),
  partition china values(3),
  partition malaysia values(4)
  );
```

I am getting ERROR:  syntax error at or near "(". What i am missing here. I am using postgres12

Comment: **Did you take days in reading the documentation of [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) ? It is open source, so you are allowed to improve it.** BTW provide some [mre] in your question...

Comment: You might (as a last resort) compile (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) the source code of PostGreSQL and run it under the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: as a side note: the database is called **PostgreSQL** (or just Postgres) - it's spelled with a lower case g.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know where you found that syntax, obviously not in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). As you can see [there](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE-EXAMPLE) partitions are created using `create table .. as partition of` in Postgres:

Define the table:

```
CREATE TABLE countrymeasurements
(
  countrycode int NOT NULL,
  countryname character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  languagename character varying (30) NOT NULL,
  daysofoperation character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  salesparts    bigint,
  replaceparts  bigint
)
PARTITION BY LIST(countrycode);
```

Define the partitions:

```
create table india 
  partition of countrymeasurements 
  for values in (1);
  
create table japan
  partition of countrymeasurements 
  for values in (2);
  
create table china
  partition of countrymeasurements 
  for values in (3);

create table malaysia
  partition of countrymeasurements 
  for values in (4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stackoverflow! Please note, that asking questions here without showing prior research may turn away people that otherwise might love to help.

In this case I checked and found no official example for list partitioning. But, if you just shorten your statement it will create a table using the values in `countrycode` column to partition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE countrymeasurements
(
  countrycode int NOT NULL,
  countryname character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  languagename character varying (30) NOT NULL,
  daysofoperation character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  salesparts    bigint,
  replaceparts  bigint
)
 PARTITION BY LIST(countrycode)
;
```

The psql describe table command shows the partitioning is as requested:

```sql
psql=# \d countrymeasurements
                    Table "public.countrymeasurements"
     Column      |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
-----------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 countrycode     | integer               |           | not null |
 countryname     | character varying(30) |           | not null |
 languagename    | character varying(30) |           | not null |
 daysofoperation | character varying(30) |           | not null |
 salesparts      | bigint                |           |          |
 replaceparts    | bigint                |           |          |
Partition key: LIST (countrycode)
```

Then you can define the partitions like in the answer from @a_horse_with_no_name. But, some notes on using such a strategy may be in order.

Notes:

- When you just allow 4 explicit partitions via list (as you tried) what happens when value 5 comes along?
- The documentation at [postgresql 12 on ddl partition ing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-partitioning.html) suggests to consider hash partitioning instead of list and choose the number of partitions instead of relying on your column values which might expose a very unbalanced abundance.

Comment: Is it possible to do Range/List Partition in Postgres9.5?

Comment: @sheiknazeeb documentation is at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/ddl-partitioning.html