# PostgreSQL10 - is it possible to do PARTITION BY LIST (col1, col2, .., colN)?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-10

I am looking at the PostgreSQL [official documentation page on Table Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html) for my version of postgres.

I would like to create table partitions over three columns, and I wish to use declarative partition with `BY LIST` method to do that.

However, I cannot seem to find a good example on how to deal with more columns, and `BY LIST` specifically.

In the aforementioned docs I only read:

> You may decide to use multiple columns in the partition key for range
> partitioning, if desired. (...) For example, consider a table range
> partitioned using columns lastname and firstname (in that order) as
> the partition key.

It seems that declarative partition on multiple columns is only for `BY RANGE` or is that not right?

However, if it is not, I found [an answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63295849/1979665) that tells me how to deal with `BY LIST` and one column. But in my case I have three columns.

My idea would be to do something like the following (I am pretty sure it's wrong):

```
CREATE TABLE my_partitioned_table (
    col1 type CONSTRAINT col1_constraint CHECK (col1 = 1 or col1 = 0),
    col2 type CONSTRAINT col2_constraint CHECK (col2 = 'A' or col2 = 'B'),
    col3 type,
    col4 type) PARTITION BY LIST (col1, col2);

CREATE TABLE part_1a PARTITION OF my_partitioned_table
    FOR VALUES IN (1, 'A');

CREATE TABLE part_1b PARTITION OF my_partitioned_tabel
    FOR VALUES IN (1, 'B');

...
```

I would need a correct implemenation as the combination of possible partitions in my case is quite a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is true, you cannot use list partitioning with more than one partitioning key. You also cannot bent range partitioning to do what you want.

But you could use a composite type to get what you want:

```
CREATE TYPE part_type AS (a integer, b text);

CREATE TABLE partme (p part_type, val text) PARTITION BY LIST (p);

CREATE TABLE partme_1_B PARTITION OF partme FOR VALUES IN (ROW(1, 'B'));

INSERT INTO partme VALUES (ROW(1, 'B'), 'x');

INSERT INTO partme VALUES (ROW(1, 'C'), 'x');
ERROR:  no partition of relation "partme" found for row
DETAIL:  Partition key of the failing row contains (p) = ((1,C)).

SELECT (p).a, (p).b, val FROM partme;

 a | b | val 
---+---+-----
 1 | B | x
(1 row)
```

But perhaps the best way to go is to use subpartitioning: partition the original table by the first column and the partitions by the second column.

Comment: thanks for the info! What about sub-partitioning? Will this be worse? like `CREATE TABLE part_1 PARTITION OF my_partitioned_table FOR VALUES IN (1) PARTITION BY LIST (col2);`

Comment: Ah, you are right. Why do you ask if you have a better idea than I do? :^)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  It is a bit hacky, but I know no reason why that shouldn't be supported.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there something in the documentation or the code that says it is not supported?